# How to install ZTE AC2726 on Karmic Koala

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-9.10, wireless-networking

I just got a ZTE AC2726 wireless broadband device for my Karmic Koala but I am not able install it as the vendor has given drivers for Jaunty and not Karmic. How do I go about it?

Comment: Ravi ,
This link might help you . http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1333535